# Combining several columns with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
Name A1 A2 A3
Andy 1 NaN NaN
Brian Nan NaN NaN
Carlos NaN 2 NaN
David NaN Nan 3
Frank 2 Nan Nan
```

For each row, in 3 columns `A1`, `A2` and `A3` there is at most one non-NaN cell. So I want to merge them into one column and remove the rows that are all NaN. So the above dataframe will become:

```
Name A A-ID
Andy 1  1
Carlos 2 2
David 3 3
Frank 2 1
```

`A-ID` will store the original column (A1, A2 or A3). The row with `Brian` is removed because all 3 columns are NaN.

Naively I can write a `for` loop to do the task, but is there a more pythonic and faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method should achieve the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {"Name": ["Andy", "Brian", "Carlos", "David", "Frank"],
     "A1": [1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2],
     "A2": [np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan],
     "A3": [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Drops rows where all A* values are NaN
df = df.dropna(subset = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], how="all")

#Sums values to produce result
df["A"] = df.sum(axis=1)

#Alternative method for getting 'A'
#df["A"] = df[["A1", "A2", "A3"]].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]

#Returns final char of column name of first non-NaN column
df["A-ID"] = df[["A1", "A2", "A3"]].apply(lambda row: row.first_valid_index()[-1], axis=1)

#Dropping old A* columns
df = df.drop(["A1", "A2", "A3"], axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

     Name    A A-ID
0    Andy  1.0    1
2  Carlos  2.0    2
3   David  3.0    3
4   Frank  2.0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to do that. probably the simplest is defining a new column which is the sum or the concatenation of the other columns

```
df["B"] = df["A1"] + df["A2"] + df["A3"]
```

then, you keep only the rows with B not null

```
df = df[df.B.notnull()]
```

Regards